# Generate the UI in client side or Server side?

Tags: javascript, performance, json

Here is two approaches:
First, write a JS UI engine on the Client side, and then communicate to server using json, when received the require json data, generate the required UI on the client side.

The second approach is the user make request, the server side get the json, generate the UI, then output the html, and inject the html code... ...

Which ways to do is better?? Thank you

Comment: Better in what way? Performance? Scalability? Flexibility? This really depends on your goals and what the UI does - sometimes a chunk of HTML is not what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already running scripts on the client the only real benefit to generating HTML for AJAX updates server-side (as opposed to pure client-side DOM manipulation) is to reuse existing control generating code that you don't want to port to JavaScript. There are several downsides to injected HTML prepared elsewhere, including security problems that will arise from the use of innerHTML.